# How to use MaterialAlertDialogBuilder fine?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, material-components-android, material-components

When i use dialog.builder the font size is correct but when i use  MaterialAlertDialogBuilder the font size of body text is smaller. its ok?

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha06'
```

Im use this theme

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
```

MaterialComponent code

```
MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this)
    .setMessage("This is a test of MaterialAlertDialogBuilder")
    .setPositiveButton("Ok", null)
    .show()
```

[image: Screenshot_20190512-115103_2]

AlertDialog.Builder

```
AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setMessage("This is a test of AlertDialog.Builder")
            .setPositiveButton("Ok", null)
            .show()
```

[image: Screenshot_20190512-115241_2]

Where is the problem?

Comment: It's totally depend on default theme of dialog which is different on both cases. you can do is to set your own style or need to create custom dialog to have more control over things related to your dialog

Comment: That’s actually intentional. `MaterialAlertDialogBuilder` is essentially `AlertDialog.Builder` but with support for the shape system and color/colour theming.

Comment: Please check my answer from [Here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59714662/9087148)

Answer (score 11):

It is intentional. They are using different styles.

You can change it using something like:

```
  <style name="Body_ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog">
    <item name="materialAlertDialogBodyTextStyle">@style/BodyMaterialAlertDialog.MaterialComponents.Body.Text</item>
  </style>
  <style name="BodyMaterialAlertDialog.MaterialComponents.Body.Text" parent="MaterialAlertDialog.MaterialComponents.Body.Text">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
  </style>
```

and then:

```
 new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this,
      R.style.Body_ThemeOverlay_MaterialComponents_MaterialAlertDialog)
            .setTitle("Title")
            .setMessage("Message......")
            ...
            .show();
```

[image][image]

Answer (score 2):

You can solve like this:

```
<item name="materialAlertDialogTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.MyApp.Dialog</item>

<style name="ThemeOverlay.MyApp.Dialog" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dialog">
    <item name="android:dialogCornerRadius" tools:targetApi="p">@dimen/dp_4</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">@dimen/dp_2</item>
    ...
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `MaterialAlertDialogBuilder` instead of `AlertDialog.Builder`.

```
MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this)
            .setMessage("This is a test of AlertDialog.Builder")
            .setPositiveButton("Ok", null)
            .show()
```

Comment: OP is already using the `MaterialAlertDialogBuilder`

Comment: @VikasPatidar OP?