# Apply style to Alert Dialogs

Tags: android, material-design, android-alertdialog, material-components, material-components-android

I decided to try material alert [dialogs](https://material.io/develop/android/components/dialog/) on android.
The problem I am having is when I try to apply some styles. Checking the docs, I found this:

```
<item name="materialAlertDialogTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog</item>
```

So I decided to try this:

```
  <style name="BaseTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">

    <item name="materialAlertDialogTheme">@style/Theme.App.MaterialDialogAlert</item>

  </style>
      <style name="Theme.App.MaterialDialogAlert" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dialog.Alert">
        <!-- FIXME: this does not work. it does not change the title appearance. -->
    <!--    <item name="materialAlertDialogTitleTextStyle">@style/TextAppearance.App.MaterialDialogAlert.Title.Text</item>-->
        <!-- FIXME: this change only the title font, not the message appearance -->
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/nunito_semi_bold</item>
        <item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/Widget.App.Button.TextButton</item>
        <item name="buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/Widget.App.Button.TextButton</item>
      </style>

    <style name="TextAppearance.App.MaterialDialogAlert.Title.Text" parent="MaterialAlertDialog.MaterialComponents.Title.Text">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/nunito_semi_bold</item>
      </style>
```

But so far I could style the buttons successfully. With the title and message I have some issues. Now I am able to apply some styles to the title with this:

```
<item name="android:fontFamily">@font/nunito_semi_bold</item>
```

But I do not think this is the proper way. First this does not apply the font to the message section. Second, I would like to apply other text styles, one for title and one for the message section.

I tried also checking this style: `MaterialAlertDialog.MaterialComponents.Title.Text` where I can see that this item is being applied at some point:

```
<item name="android:textAppearance">?attr/textAppearanceSubtitle1</item>
```

So I decided to declare this in my base theme:

```
<style name="BaseTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="textAppearanceSubtitle1">@style/TextAppearance.App.Subtitle1</item>
  </style>

  <style name="TextAppearance.App.Subtitle1" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Subtitle1">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/nunito_semi_bold</item>
  </style>
```

but nothing changed.

So my questions are:

1. How can I do this properly using theme / styles.
2. What am I doing wrong with my current code?

EDIT
I tried using this too:

```
  <style name="Theme.App.MaterialDialogAlert" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="materialAlertDialogTitleTextStyle">@style/Dialog.App.MaterialDialogAlert.Title.Text</item>
    <item name="materialAlertDialogBodyTextStyle">@style/TextAppearance.App.MaterialDialogAlert.Body.Text</item>
    <item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/Widget.App.Button.TextButton</item>
    <item name="buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/Widget.App.Button.TextButton</item>
  </style>

  <style name="Dialog.App.MaterialDialogAlert.Title.Text" parent="MaterialAlertDialog.MaterialComponents.Title.Text">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.App.Subtitle1</item>
  </style>

  <style name="TextAppearance.App.Subtitle1" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Subtitle1">
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/nunito_semi_bold</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/nunito_semi_bold</item>
  </style>
```

But it is not working.

Also I tried this from the material components [repo](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android):

```
  <style name="Theme.App.MaterialDialogAlert" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="materialAlertDialogTitleTextStyle">@style/Dialog.App.MaterialDialogAlert.Title.Text</item>
    <item name="materialAlertDialogBodyTextStyle">@style/Dialog.App.MaterialDialogAlert.Body.Text</item>
    <item name="buttonBarButtonStyle">@style/Widget.App.Button.TextButton</item>
  </style>

  <style name="Dialog.App.MaterialDialogAlert.Title.Text" parent="MaterialAlertDialog.MaterialComponents.Title.Text">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.App.Subtitle1</item>
  </style>

  <style name="Dialog.App.MaterialDialogAlert.Body.Text" parent="@style/MaterialAlertDialog.MaterialComponents.Body.Text">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.Body2</item>
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/nunito_regular</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/nunito_regular</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/color_error</item>
  </style>
```

but does not work.

The only think I could customise was the title by adding this to the theme:

```
<item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/Dialog.App.MaterialDialogAlert.Title.Text</item>
```

---

I was checking the code inside the library and I can see that this layout is being used: [mtrl_alert_dialog.xml](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/e22d745ec096154ee0028c2dd180ea4ae6248eda/lib/java/com/google/android/material/dialog/res/layout/mtrl_alert_dialog.xml)

There I can see this:

```
<TextView
            android:id="@android:id/message"
            style="?attr/materialAlertDialogBodyTextStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="?attr/dialogPreferredPadding"
            android:paddingRight="?attr/dialogPreferredPadding"/>
```

where we can see a reference to materialAlertDialogBodyTextStyle. So maybe it is a bug in the library?

Comment: Please check my answer for Material Dialog [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59714662/9087148)

Answer (score 6):

You can use this style to customize the title and the body:

```
<style name="Theme.App.MaterialDialogAlert" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog">
    <!-- Title -->
    <item name="materialAlertDialogTitleTextStyle">@style/MyTitle_MaterialAlertDialog</item>
    <!-- Body -->
    <item name="materialAlertDialogBodyTextStyle">@style/BodyTextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Body2</item>
</style>
```

Then define the style for the **title**:

```
<style name="MyTitle_MaterialAlertDialog" parent="@style/MaterialAlertDialog.MaterialComponents.Title.Text">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/MyTitle_TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Subtitle1</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTitle_TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Subtitle1" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Subtitle1">
    <item name="fontFamily">.....</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">....</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">.....</item>
</style>
```

Then define for the **body**:

```
  <style name="BodyTextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Body2" parent="@style/MaterialAlertDialog.MaterialComponents.Body.Text">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/....</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
    <item name="fontFamily">.....</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">....</item>
  </style>
```

[image][image]

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. I tried this but it is not working. I am using 1.1.0-beta02. Which version are you using.

Comment: @LeandroOcampo Updated the answer. It works with 1.1.0-beta02 and 1.2.0-alpha01

Comment: I updated my question. I tried with the repo from MC but it is not working either and they are using 1.2.0-alpha01, so I am surprised it works with you. But your answer makes total sense when I check the internals of the library. So I don't know what can be the issue.

Comment: @LeandroOcampo It is quite strange and I don't understand where is your issue. Did you try `new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this, R.style.Theme_App_MaterialDialogAlert)....show();` just to skip the  `materialAlertDialogTheme` attr in the app theme?

Comment: Thank you for mentioning both "fontFamily" and "android:fontFamily" in text style. It's working on any api only when using both of them.

Comment: Where do you use `BodyTextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Body2` ?

Comment: @ChVas Thanks for your feedback. I've ppdated the answer.

Comment: Why does code completion give `ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dialog.Alert` instead of `ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog`?

Comment: @Mark I don't know it but the correct themeoverlay in this case is `ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog`.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti yeah, it looks like one is for use with `alertDialogTheme` and the other for use with `materialAlertDialogTheme` but for some reason `ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog` doesn't auto-complete. Super confusing https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/dialog/res/values/themes.xml#L60

Comment: It's real kind of magic... Your similar answer on github didn't work but this one works. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Apply this style first :

```
     <style name="MaterialAlertDialogRoundedStyle" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog">
    <item name="shapeAppearanceOverlay">
        @style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MaterialAlertDialog.Rounded
    </item>// For rounded dialog
    <item name="materialAlertDialogTitleTextStyle">
        @style/TitleMaterialAlertDialog.MaterialComponents.Title.Text
    </item>//to change title text properties of dialog
    <item name="materialAlertDialogBodyTextStyle">
        @style/BodyMaterialAlertDialog.MaterialComponents.Body.Text
    </item>//to change body text properties of dialog
</style>

<style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MaterialAlertDialog.Rounded" parent="">
    <item name="cornerSize">@dimen/_10sdp</item>
</style>

<style name="TitleMaterialAlertDialog.MaterialComponents.Title.Text" parent="MaterialAlertDialog.MaterialComponents.Title.Text">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/_14ssp</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/montserrat_semi_bold</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
</style>

<style name="BodyMaterialAlertDialog.MaterialComponents.Body.Text" parent="MaterialAlertDialog.MaterialComponents.Body.Text">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/_12ssp</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/MyTitle_TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Subtitle1</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTitle_TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Subtitle1" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Subtitle1">
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/montserrat_regular</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/montserrat_regular</item>
</style>
```

Than you this code to open dialog:

```
MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(
        context,
        R.style.MaterialAlertDialogRoundedStyle
    )
        .setTitle(getText(R.string.app_name))
        .setMessage(getString(R.string.are_you_sure_you_want_to_logout))
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton(getText(R.string.ok)) { dialog, _ ->
            dialog.dismiss()
        }
        .setNegativeButton(getText(R.string.cancel)) { dialog, _ ->
            dialog.dismiss()
        }
        .show()
```